# How can i get below image type view of Floating Action Button in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, floating-action-button

I know how to set floating action button like shown in bellow image. But i need to show different layout on click or anytime when i want to show that layout. second layout is attached

[image]

[image]

How can i achieve this?

Comment: The FAB u talking about us a animation with morphing effects. `Swiggy`

Comment: How can i do this? how to set this type of layout on click of FAB?

Comment: read more here https://github.com/hujiaweibujidao/FabDialogMorph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer this link Floating Action Button Toolbar https://github.com/AlexKolpa/fab-toolbar

There you need to add dependency in the project.

```
compile 'com.github.alexkolpa:floating-action-button-toolbar:0.5.1'
```

In your XML file,

```
<com.github.alexkolpa.fabtoolbar.FabToolbar
android:id="@+id/fab_toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="bottom"
tb:tb_anim_duration="500"
tb:tb_button_gravity="end"
tb:tb_container_gravity="center"
>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/attach"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_attachment_white_48dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/icon_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/icon_margin"
    />

<!-- More buttons can be added here -->
```

To hide or show the Toolbar, simply call `hide()` and `show()`.

```
FabToolbar fabToolbar = ((FabToolbar) findViewById(R.id.fab_toolbar));

findViewById(R.id.attach).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        fabToolbar.hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: This is what i need. Thanks. But need to implement first

Comment: As I can see you don't have enough reputation to post a comment so you simply provided a link as an answer but its incomplete , you must provide a working and important code sample as well and also share alink to read the complete post

Comment: Updated the answer. Thanks!

Comment: It's my pleasure! Thanks!